# How to restore Meizu Pro 5 Ubuntu Edition to Factory Settings

Tags: boot, ubuntu-touch

I tried installing Libertine on my phone to take advantage of installing some legacy apps. The install failed due to some dependency issues. No big deal I thought. But my phone got reset and when I tried to access the on screen keyboard, it no longer existed.

I'm hoping to be able to reset the phone to it's factory settings but I do not know how. The hard reset doesn't work as the Ubuntu logo appears on the screen and no options are available.

Comment: http://www.hardreset.info/devices/meizu/meizu-pro-5-ubuntu-edition/

Comment: Thank you for the response but it doesn't work on the Ubuntu version. It brings up the Ubuntu Logo and the screen appears frozen with no options.

Comment: I believe this is actually the hard reset for the Android version. I cannot access the Developer Mode in order to ADB into and restore it that way. I'm in a bit of a pickle.

Answer (score 0):

It was my understanding that the power off and the on then with on with volume buttons was the andriod reset. I have had a look for the factory reset in storage, but cannot see it. However, if you go to Settings and then Reset you have the option to Erase & Reset Everythibg. This looks like it may be your best option. If this does not work have a look at raising a Launchpad ticket for it.